# react-native dosent update any code

Tags: react-native

my steps:

1. installed node.js
2. `npm install -g react-native-cli`
3. `react-native init AwesomeProject`
4. 1.cmd=mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
5. cmd=react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
6. `react-native run-android` (react packager ready and building 100% without any error)

Showing app default **index.android.js**
after that i close everything and change simple code in **index.android.js**
run again with `react-native run-android` (react packager ready and building 100% without any error)
showing me again default **index.android.js**
why this happening to me ?
Windows 7,real device android 4.2.2 with usb connected

Comment: do you have the react-native server running?

Comment: yes its running. i dont want to same time change code cuz of its not supporting for 4.2 .I can do `react-native run-android` after change code but its not work

Comment: maybe there is a bug in your code if the default project ran properly.

Comment: i change just  "Welcome to React Native!">"Welcome to React Native!asd"

Comment: hmm that is strange. Maybe try to uninstall the app from your phone, as well as making sure you saved the edited code.

Comment: i did but not work also when i recreate react-native project and change code after run its working for once. after change something same issues

Comment: if u want to see my steps in my computer, i can. i already spend 3 days.

Comment: Have you developed using react native before? If not, I recommend looking at a tutorial and following along to see if you could have possibly missed something.

Comment: my first develop react native but i alot develop android apps. i follow react native own page and i watch few videos about how to install react native

Comment: i found solution at last ♥
here's my steps:
1-install or upgrade all react native stuffs
2-react-native init projectname
3-cd projectname
4-cmd(1) yarn start eject
5-cmd(2) react-native run-android
6-after opened "red screen app" click dismis
7-inside of app click menu, select "dev settings"
8-select "debug server host & port for ... " write your pc ip like 192.168.1.2:8081
9-close app and open app
if it dosent work contact with me here maybe i can help you about that